# Cannot access file trying to send a file stream

Tags: .net, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'd like to send a file stream (an SQLite database file). I got:

> Sqlite3 in ASP.NET Core faced System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

```
private void UpdateTestCaseDbFiles(string dnFile)
{
    string strConn = @"Data Source=" + dnFile;

    SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder(strConn);
    builder.Pooling = false;

    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();

    SQLiteConnection.ClearPool(conn);

    SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
}
```

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27139), I put disable but it's not working. After calling the function I send the file stream:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); --exception.
return File(fileStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
```

Comment: Have you tried with GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); before reading the file?

Comment: Yes I did and seems not working to get access database.

Comment: Forcing a garbage collection doesn't help *if the database file is in use*. The code leaks connections and streams, especially in case of errors. Declare connections and streams in a `using` block to ensure they're closed even if an exception is thrown. DbConnection.Dispose is the same as Close so there's no need to call both. Add `Pooling=False;` to the connection string to avoid using the connection pool entirely. Even if you close a connection, the database file may still be locked by the connection pool.

Comment: Which SQLite library are you using? Which version? Connection pooling isn't a feature of SQLite itself. The `Pooling` keyword works in [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite v6 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#pooling). The [current stable version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/) is 7.0.8

Comment: It seems the SQLite library is the old `System.Data.SQLite.dll`. Actually it can be distinguished from the class name convention. The old `System.Data.SQLite.dll` uses class names like `SQLiteConnection` but the new `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` uses `SqliteConnection`.

Comment: If your retry logic has solved the issue, you may want to answer your own question. Don't provide an answer in the question itself. By the way, the `GC.Collect()` call in the catch clause is probably useless. I think it is the `Thread.Sleep()` call that solves the issue since the connection may not be closed immediately in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround might be **taking a DB backup within your application first and then using that backup file while you create your stream**. The backup file will not be in a locked state.

You can use this method to create a backup file:

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string sourceDbPath, string destinationDbPath)
{
    using var sourceDbConnection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={sourceDbPath}; Version=3;");
    using var destinationDbConnection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={destinationDbPath}; Version=3;");
    sourceDbConnection.Open();
    destinationDbConnection.Open();
    sourceDbConnection.BackupDatabase(destinationDbConnection, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
}
```

You can then delete the newly created backup file, if you wish.